# Replace null values with 0 in PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, isnull

I tried to convert the (null) values with 0 (zeros) output in PIVOT function but have no success.

Below is the table and the syntax I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT isnull([DayLoad],0) FROM #Temp1
```

Data in the table `#Temp1`:

```
zone  dayB    templt cid  DayLoad
other 10      other   1    2020-05-28
other 10      other   1    2020-05-29
other 10      other   1    2020-05-30
other 10      other   1    2020-05-31
other 4       other   1    2020-06-02
other 10      other   1    2020-06-02
other 10      other   1    2020-06-01
```

My request:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DayLoad], 106) + ']', 
                                  '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DayLoad], 106) + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DayLoad] FROM #Temp1) PV  
               ORDER BY [DayLoad]

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
              SELECT *
                      into #temptable
                      FROM 
             (
                 SELECT 

                ''''+[zone]+'' ''          + ''''+convert(varchar(50),[dayB])+''''+''+''           +'' ''+(case when [templt]=''Прочее'' then '''' else [templt] end)+''''    as [zone/dayB]
                ,[DayLoad]
                ,[cid]
                ,[dayB]
                ,[zone]
                FROM #Temp1
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 sum([cid])  
                 FOR [DayLoad] IN ('+ @cols + ')
            ) p 

select *
from #temptable            
order by [zone],[dayB]

drop table #temptable      
            '     
EXEC(@query)
DROP TABLE #Temp1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below example, when you have nulls and empty string, right option is to go with case statement,

```
SELECT DISTINCT case when ([DayLoad] is null or [DayLoad] = '') then 0 else [DayLoad] end FROM #Temp1
```